# Deep Array of Objects sum using Lodash

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object, lodash

I have a dataset that currently looks like this :

```
let cart_items =  [
      {
        "id": "817fd815-302c-401a-b087-6781f073a2bf",
        "date": "2021-09-10",
        "notes": "null",
        "quantity": 2,
        "is_special": true,
        "mobile_price": "1.21",
        "item_name": "Cranberry",
        "menu_name": "Breakfast",
        "item_photo": "loading",
        "cart_add_ons": [
        ]
      }, 
      {
        "id": "817fd815-302c-401a-b087-6781f073a2bf",
        "date": "2021-09-11",
        "notes": "null",
        "quantity": 2,
        "is_special": true,
        "mobile_price": "7.21",
        "item_name": "Cranberry",
        "menu_name": "Breakfast",
        "item_photo": "loading",
        "cart_add_ons": [
          {
            "name": "Cake",
            "mobile_price": "2.3"
          },
          {
            "name": "Milk",
            "mobile_price": "12"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "817fd815-302c-401a-b087-6781f073a2bf",
        "date": "2021-09-10",
        "notes": "null",
        "quantity": 2,
        "is_special": true,
        "mobile_price": "5.21",
        "item_name": "Raspberry",
        "menu_name": "Breakfast",
        "item_photo": "loading",
        "cart_add_ons": [
          {
            "name": "Cake",
            "mobile_price": "2.3"
          },
          {
            "name": "Milk",
            "mobile_price": "12"
          }
        ]
      }
    ];
```

I am essentially trying to sum all the add_on prices in cart_add_ons if cart_add_ons has any data at all.

I am trying to use the following way to achieve this, but I know this is not correct. Is it anything close to the correct solution?

```
result = _.chain(cart_items)
      .groupBy('date')
      .map((value, key) => ({
        date: key,
        total_amount: _.sumBy(value, item => Number(item.mobile_price)),
        total_add_on: _.sumBy(value, function(o) { return o.cart_add_ons ? Number(o.cart_add_ons.mobile_price) : 0; }),
        item_data: value,
      }))
      .sortBy('date')
      .value();
```

BTW, this is the result of the above problem :

```
[
   {
      "date": "2021-09-10",
      "total_amount": 6.42,
      "total_add_on": null,
      "item_data": [
         {
            "id": "817fd815-302c-401a-b087-6781f073a2bf",
            "date": "2021-09-10",
            "notes": "null",
            "quantity": 2,
            "is_special": true,
            "mobile_price": "1.21",
            "item_name": "Cranberry",
            "menu_name": "Breakfast",
            "item_photo": "loading",
            "cart_add_ons": []
         },
         {
            "id": "817fd815-302c-401a-b087-6781f073a2bf",
            "date": "2021-09-10",
            "notes": "null",
            "quantity": 2,
            "is_special": true,
            "mobile_price": "5.21",
            "item_name": "Raspberry",
            "menu_name": "Breakfast",
            "item_photo": "loading",
            "cart_add_ons": [
               {
                  "name": "Cake",
                  "mobile_price": "2.3"
               },
               {
                  "name": "Milk",
                  "mobile_price": "12"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "date": "2021-09-11",
      "total_amount": 7.21,
      "total_add_on": null,
      "item_data": [
         {
            "id": "817fd815-302c-401a-b087-6781f073a2bf",
            "date": "2021-09-11",
            "notes": "null",
            "quantity": 2,
            "is_special": true,
            "mobile_price": "7.21",
            "item_name": "Cranberry",
            "menu_name": "Breakfast",
            "item_photo": "loading",
            "cart_add_ons": [
               {
                  "name": "Cake",
                  "mobile_price": "2.3"
               },
               {
                  "name": "Milk",
                  "mobile_price": "12"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Please let me know where I am going wrong on this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I got the answer.
However, I am keeping this out here, if it helps anyone.

```
  result = _.chain(cart_items)
      .groupBy('date')
      .map((value, key) => ({
        date: key,
        total_amount: _.sumBy(value, item => Number(item.mobile_price)),
        total_add_on: _.sumBy(value, function(item) { return item.cart_add_ons ? _.sumBy(item.cart_add_ons, k => Number(k.mobile_price)) : 0; }),
        item_data: value,
      }))
      .sortBy('date')
      .value();
```

**We can chain _.sumBy() to loop through the inner array of objects (cart_add_ons) if there is one, and then sum the mobile_prices.**